# Image comparison using Karate UI

Tags: karate, image-comparison

I want to compare two images and identify if they are same or different.Can it be possible using Karate UI. If anyone had done similar logic in Karate Ui or integrating files with Karate please share some insights or git link ?

Comment: Official Doc:https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#compare-image

Comment: Yes the above doc helped